# Program printing all SubSequences of array in C, prints same SubSequence two times

Tags: arrays, c, recursion

I'm trying to print out all possible SubSequences of the given array.

my current code works to a certain point, but have some error. In case of given array is `{1,2,3}`

the expected output is

```
0 0 0 
3 0 0 
2 0 0 
2 3 0 
1 0 0 
1 3 0 
1 2 0 
1 2 3
```

but my output is

```
0 0 0 
3 0 0 
2 0 0 
2 3 0 
1 3 0 
1 3 0 
1 2 0 
1 2 3
```

The problem is my code prints `1 3 0` two times not printing `1 0 0`. Can anyone help me what caused this error in my code, please?

Here is my current code

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printAllSubSequences(int arr[], int index1, int  arr2[], int index2){
    
    if (index1 >= 3) {

        for(int i = 0; i < 3 ; i++){
            printf("%d ", arr2[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        return;
     }
     
    printAllSubSequences(arr, index1+1, arr2, index2);
    arr2[index2] = arr[index1];
    printAllSubSequences(arr, index1+1, arr2, index2+1);
}

int main(){
    int arr[3] = {1, 2, 3};
    int arr2[3];
    printAllSubSequences(arr, 0, arr2, 0);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: on this [website](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/world-codesprint-5/challenges/longest-increasing-subsequence-arrays#:~:text=A%20subsequence%20of%20an%20array,ordering%20as%20the%20original%20array.&text=The%20longest%20increasing%20subsequence%20of,elements%20are%20in%20increasing%20order.) it is said to be subsequences of array {1,2,3} are { }, {1}, {2}, {3}, {1,2}, {1,3}, {2,3}, {1,2,3}

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I think you are confusing between **subsequence** and **subarray**. In my opinion the OP is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code is that after you initialized `arr2[index2] = arr[index1];` you did not initialize it back to `0`. Since the arrays in C or C++ are pass by reference, any change in any of the indices in any of recursive function call will reflect in successive function calls.

Hence, once you use `arr2[index2] = arr[index1];`, you also need to do `arr2[index2] = 0;` after the function call. Another thing, you need to initialize `arr2` with `0` while declaring. It might work on your compiler but not in general. It is always a good practice to initialize it to `0`.

Here's the corrected code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printAllSubSequences(int arr[], int index1, int  arr2[], int index2){
    
    if (index1 >= 3) {

        for(int i = 0; i < 3 ; i++){
            printf("%d ", arr2[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        return;
     }
     
    printAllSubSequences(arr, index1+1, arr2, index2);
    arr2[index2] = arr[index1];
    printAllSubSequences(arr, index1+1, arr2, index2+1);
    arr2[index2] = 0;
}

int main(){
    int arr[3] = {1, 2, 3};
    int arr2[3] = {0};
    printAllSubSequences(arr, 0, arr2, 0);
    printf("\n");
}
```